# Alternative Monero implementations

Tags: monerod, daemon, source

Considering the hardforks planned in Monero, it seems that having several implementations of the daemon is a difficult task as they would need to be kept in sync.

I wondered however:

- Have there been projects to produce alternative implementations of the Monero daemon (I only know of the official c++ version)?
- Would it be useful for the community to have more than one implementation?

Comment: I seem to remember a Reddit post from a Linux developer about his python implementation, but since I can't find it right now, I may be misremembering it.

Answer (score 3):

An old experiment of alternative implementation of Monero can be https://github.com/monero-project/mininero

It's not an alternative for Monero but an alternative for RingCT transactions.